# how to detect logout of asp.net 4 session

Tags: asp.net

How do you detect when a user logs out using the ASP.Net 4 session management?  I have a site that is using the <LoginTemplate> with a <LoginStatus> control.  When the user clicks the "Log out" link, it should fire the LoggingOut event of the LoginStatus, but I cannot get it to do so.  Is there another way to detect when the user logs out of the application?  Session_End isn't being fired because the session itself is still valid, just that the user isn't logged in.

Comment: `LoginStatus.LoggingOut` should fire after that click.  Could you post applicable markup and code-behind?  Did you check to see if `LoginStatus.LoggedOut` was not firing as well?  How did you check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found my problem. The LoginTemplate control obliterates the LoginStatus's LoggingOut event. Once I created my own header it works

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`LoginStatus.LoggedOut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginstatus.loggedout.aspx) Event. I have used it in the past and it seemed very reliable..

Answer (score 0):

Session.Abandon()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310.aspx

Here is a little more detail on the HttpSessionState object:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate_members.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`LoginStatus.LoggedOut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginstatus.loggedout.aspx) event - it is right you need, I think.

> Raised after the user clicks the logout link and the logout process is complete.